# Converting text date to date in Arcade

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I am attempting to convert string which is formatted like MM/DD/YYYY to an actual date format in Arcade on ArcGIS Online. This is the code I am using.

```
var cd = split($feature["DATE_"], " ")
var dates = split(cd[1], "/")
var m = dates[0]
var d = dates[1]
var y = dates[2]
return Text(Date(m, d, y), 'MMMM D, Y')
```

The output in the example instance that I am using should be August 26, 2019 but it spits out July 9, 1915. The issue is in the last line somewhere, as returning y gives 2019, d gives 26, and m gives 8.

Does anybody know why it may be outputting the incorrect date?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using the date function is incorrect. If you follow the [date function documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/date_functions/#date) you will see that the year comes first, not month. Try this:

```
var cd = split('08 26 2019', " ")
console(cd)
var dates = cd
var m = dates[0] - 1 // Month 0 is January
var d = dates[1]
var y = dates[2]
console(m,d,y)
return Text(Date(y, m, d), 'MMMM D, Y')
```